# Why does NetworkX draw directed graph edges with stubs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

NetworkX documentation for the function `draw_networkx_edges` claims:

> For directed graphs, "arrows" (actually just thicker stubs) are drawn at the head end... Yes, it is ugly but drawing proper arrows with Matplotlib this way is tricky.

Last time I checked, [drawing an arrow in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html) is anything but tricky. Does anyone know what is the *real* reason for drawing the stubs?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but if you look at how an edge is drawn in the code, it is a line segment from one node's position to the other node's position.  The node is drawn over top of the edges.  If the node is large, it will completely cover the arrowhead (unless it's a huge arrowhead), and even if the node is not large, it will cover the tip of the arrowhead, which will look bad.  Using a thicker line line at the end makes these issues not so bad.

The alternative is to figure out how to have the arrowhead end at the border of the node it is pointing to.  Of course, when the edge is drawn, that node may not yet be drawn.  So you would need to make the arrowhead location change dynamically based on how large the user decides to make the node.  I think that's probably quite hard (at least I don't have an idea how to do it).

Comment: An arrow may be drawn half way, in the middle of an edge.